# How to maintain alignment when the window size changes CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my first time working with CSS on a webpage and I'm having alignment troubles.  The problem is that whenever I resize the window I'm viewing my webpage in, the elements on the page lose their alignment because they are set at fixed widths.  I have three CSS classes as detailed below.

```
.left {
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      text-align: right;
}
.right {
      width: 65%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      float:left;
}
.center {
    width: 87%;    
    text-align: center; 
}
```

How can I fix this so that my headers (which use the 'center' class stay aligned directly above my text boxes (using the 'right' class)

Comment: Please share the HTML as well. Just the relevent parts please. Or Better still provide a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Regardless of your code these two articles will help you out. They're great in explaining fluid and responsive design, which will solve even more problems than your facing now: http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Comment: I recommend you to use a grid/css framework to solve the problem. no make you work easier also can solve the issue cross the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and calculate the padding and all when the window resizes.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
#alwaysCentered{
background: #D4D4D4;
width: 175px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="alwaysCentered">I will always be centered</div>

<script>
alwaysCenteredMarginLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#alwaysCentered').width()) / 2
alwaysCenteredMarginTop = ($(window).height() - $('#alwaysCentered').height()) / 2;
    $('#alwaysCentered').css({
        'margin-left' : alwaysCenteredMarginLeft,
        'margin-top' : alwaysCenteredMarginTop
    });

    window.onresize = function(event) {
    alwaysCenteredMarginLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#alwaysCentered').width()) / 2
alwaysCenteredMarginTop = ($(window).height() - $('#alwaysCentered').height()) / 2;
    $('#alwaysCentered').css({
        'margin-left' : alwaysCenteredMarginLeft,
        'margin-top' : alwaysCenteredMarginTop
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This's not an answer. Write on comment please